# Dynamically set the android:noHistory attribute

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm stuck between a rock and a hard place. I am developing an application that shows a welcome page and asks a user to either register or sign in. A user can go to and from registration/sign in activity to main activity (welcome page) by up caret button and a phone's back button.

But once a user logs in or creates an account, I'd like both the main activity (welcome page) and previous activity (could either be login activity or register activity) to be removed from the application's stack so when a user taps a back button, they'd exit the application instead of going back to the activity they came from (either login or registration). 
I can't set the `android:noHistory="true"` on registration and sign in activity in `AndroidManifest` as it'd also mean exiting from the application from that particular activity instead of going back to welcome page. 
So, how can I dynamically set the `noHistory` flag on these activities upon reaching a particular activity? Or maybe there's something wrong with the application flow that I have in mind.
Appreciate your help, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest you close the undesired Activities by using a broadcast reciever. I'll outline the steps here:-

1. Create an Acitvity to be used as a super class for the dangling Acitivies. They will listen for a custom broadcast message and call finish() when receiving the message.

   ```
   public class LoginFinisherActivity extends Activity {
       private FinishReceiver finishReceiver;
       public static final String ACTION_FINISH_LOGIN = "ACTION_FINISH_LOGIN";

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           finishReceiver= new FinishReceiver();
           registerReceiver(finishReceiver, new IntentFilter(ACTION_FINISH_LOGIN));
       }

       @Override
       protected void onDestroy() {
           super.onDestroy();
           unregisterReceiver(finishReceiver);
       }

       private final class FinishReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
           @Override
           public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
               if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_FINISH_LOGIN))
                   finish();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Any class that you don't want left dangling should extend `LoginFinisherActivity`.
3. When you reach a point where you know you don't want those activities anymore, get rid of them by sending the broadcast (for example in the onCreate() of some other Activity): `sendBroadcast(new Intent(LoginFinisherActivity.ACTION_FINISH_LOGIN));`

To summarise: Essentially there are 2 classes of activities that are in you scenario - early ones that you want cleaned up - let's call them 'registration' activities and activities that you land at when you are done with the previous flow (this may just be a single activity in your app?) - let's call them the 'landing' activities. So all you need to do in have all of your 'registration' activities extend `LoginFinisherActivity` and all of your 'landing' activities to call `sendBroadcast(new Intent(LoginFinisherActivity.ACTION_FINISH_LOGIN));` in their `onCreate()`.

I hope this works for you!

Comment: That's actually a very elegant solution. I was thinking on the same lines but without a designated class and functions implementation. Thought I should destroy the welcome activity once a user went from there to sign in/register and create the activity if user presses the back button.
Same for the registration/log in: destroy the activity after loading the main activity of the app.

Comment: Moreover, could you please elobrate the code a little bit? I'm new to Java programming.

Comment: Could you be more specific on what part you need more detail on? I thought my answer was pretty detailed, but happy to provide more info!

Comment: Actually the entire flow of it and where should I extend this class (I'm assuming in welcome activity and sign up/sign in, right?) And where do I call the `sendBroadcast` function? When creating the NavigationActivity (that is the activity that shall be the entry point and tapping back button shall close the entire application).
Greatly appreciate your help as I learning my way into Android and Java.

Comment: I have edit my post (see section 'To summarise'). Hopefully this will make it more clear to you.

Comment: Understood completely. It worked like a charm. Thank you for the assistance, Nebo.